# How to use multiple authentication plugins in the same service in Kong

Tags: kubernetes, devops, cypress, kong, kong-plugin

I am looking to use Cypress for end to end testing for some kubernetes applications. Typically,  I access these applications via OIDC through kong, however cypress doesn't support this,  but does support key-auth via an API key. Is there a way of setting up the service so that I can use both of these simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot use more than one authentication plugin in an XOR scenario. This would only work for AND as long as the plugins do not use the same headers.

I also faced this problem and I solved it by setting up one service (pointing to the backend) and multiple routes (one for normal traffic, one for test traffic). You then can activate different plugins on each route instead of sticking it to the service.

The only downside is the slightly different base path you use for testing, but I think this is less problematic than the downside of testing with a different way of authentication.